# Disable Bootstrap validator after form is validated

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, validation

I am running a PHP sign-up form with Bootstrap validation. After clicking on submit button, when the form gets validated, it doesn't redirect to login page and values aren't stored in database.

How can I disable Bootstrap validation after it validates?
 Clicking submit button should redirect to login page. When I don't use Bootstrap validator it works normally.

**JavaScript code**(bootstrap validator)

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').bootstrapValidator({
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                        stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                        notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your first name'
                    }
                }
            },
             last_name: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 2,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your last name'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your email address'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'Please supply a valid email address'
                    }
                }
            },
            phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your phone number'
                    },
                    phone: {
                        country: 'US',
                        message: 'Please supply a vaild phone number with area code'
                    }
                }
            },
            address: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 8,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your street address'
                    }
                }
            },
            city: {
                validators: {
                     stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                    },
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your city'
                    }
                }
            },
            state: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please select your state'
                    }
                }
            },
            zip: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please supply your zip code'
                    },
                    zipCode: {
                        country: 'US',
                        message: 'Please supply a vaild zip code'
                    }
                }
            },

            }
        })
        .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow") // Do something ...
                $('#contact_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();

            // Get the form instance
            var $form = $(e.target);

            // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
            var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

            // Use Ajax to submit form data
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }, 'json');
        });
});
```

**PHP code**(CONNECTION TO DATABASE)

```
<?php include 'conn.php'; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    extract($_POST);

    /*$imagetype=$_FILES["product_photo"]['type'];
    $imagesize=$_FILES["product_photo"]['size'];
    $imageArr=$_FILES['product_photo'];
    move_uploaded_file($imageArr['tmp_name'], 'img/'.$imageArr['name']);
    $product_photo=$imageArr['name'];*/


    $query="insert into form (first_name,last_name,password,email,phone,address,city,state,zip) values ('$first_name','$last_name','$password','$email','$phone','$address','$city','$state','$zip')";
    if ($conn->query($query)==true) {
        header("location:login.php");       # code...
    }
    else{
        echo "Sorry , data not inserted";
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML code**(Sign Up form!)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Contact form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>



  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="insertmaster.php" method="post"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Sign Up!</legend>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"  type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="(845)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Address</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="city" placeholder="city" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" >
      <option value=" " >Please select your state</option>
      <option>Alabama</option>
      <option>Alaska</option>
      <option >Arizona</option>
      <option >Arkansas</option>
      <option >California</option>
      <option >Colorado</option>
      <option >Connecticut</option>
      <option >Delaware</option>
      <option >District of Columbia</option>
      <option> Florida</option>
      <option >Georgia</option>
      <option >Hawaii</option>
      <option >daho</option>
      <option >Illinois</option>
      <option >Indiana</option>
      <option >Iowa</option>
      <option> Kansas</option>
      <option >Kentucky</option>
      <option >Louisiana</option>
      <option>Maine</option>
      <option >Maryland</option>
      <option> Mass</option>
      <option >Michigan</option>
      <option >Minnesota</option>
      <option>Mississippi</option>
      <option>Missouri</option>
      <option>Montana</option>
      <option>Nebraska</option>
      <option>Nevada</option>
      <option>New Hampshire</option>
      <option>New Jersey</option>
      <option>New Mexico</option>
      <option>New York</option>
      <option>North Carolina</option>
      <option>North Dakota</option>
      <option>Ohio</option>
      <option>Oklahoma</option>
      <option>Oregon</option>
      <option>Pennsylvania</option>
      <option>Rhode Island</option>
      <option>South Carolina</option>
      <option>South Dakota</option>
      <option>Tennessee</option>
      <option>Texas</option>
      <option> Uttah</option>
      <option>Vermont</option>
      <option>Virginia</option>
      <option >Washington</option>
      <option >West Virginia</option>
      <option>Wisconsin</option>
      <option >Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control"  type="text">
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<!-- Text area -->

<!-- Success message -->

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
**

> LOGIN PAGE code(where it should redirect after everything validates)

**


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Login Form</title>
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>


      
      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

      
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">

        <form class="well form-horizontal" action=" " method="post"  id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Login Now!</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">UserName</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input  name="first_name" placeholder="UserName" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Password</label> 
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"  type="password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text area -->
      
    <!-- Success message -->

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
        </div><!-- /.container -->
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why do you have the `e.preventDefault();` inside `.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {`. Can you remove that and give it a try ?

Comment: i tried but nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

I have found no problem in your code, but problem with the bootstrap validator library version you are using. Maybe something is wrong with version mismatch. I got it working simply by updating the validator library version. Hope it helps.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js'></script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kn4wy60g/

Comment: nope...just your alert message popped up...neither the sign up page saves the values in database nor it redirects to login page..i want to disable the validator after everything validates...

Comment: in the fiddle i do not have permission to post and i do not have your post controller, so it obviously wont work in fiddle. you should do it on your site. your main problem was on validation success, it was not firing the success event which is resolved, now you need to do whatever you wanted inside it. thanks.

Comment: actually i did it on my site only..i also updated bootstrap validator script as you told both on LOGIN page and SIGN UP page..where required..still no response...